# Intrinsic curvature without coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, spherical-geometry

Can curvature (of a surface) be derived without coordinates and completely intrinsically?

For flat space two meeting lines would diverge from each other at a constant rate as you go along them. The separation would be 2 sin ¶ l, where ¶ is the angle and l distance along the line.the rate of separation is than 2 sin ¶

What would that deviation be for a sphere. Could this be calculated only from within the sphere and without coordinates?

Could it be derived from axioms of spherical geometry

Comment: You may find Wikipedia [Gaussian curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature) helpful.

Comment: It's not. It uses a set of basis vectors in the definition

Comment: I searched the article. Basis is not mentioned in it. Coordinates are not mentioned. It states "Gaussian curvature is an intrinsic measure of curvature, depending only on distances that are measured on the surface, not on the way it is isometrically embedded in Euclidean space."

Comment: You will have to ignore the part about "normal planes" since that depends on the way it is embedded in space. Instead measure the relation between circumference versus radius of circles embedded in the surface centered at a specific point.

Comment: For a sphere with circumference O, o(r) =O(1-cos(2pi r/o), flat space o=2 pi r, but I don't know how to derive or use this for the deviation of  deviation of two intersecting geodesics(great circles) how do I even derive the area of a sphere. All without coordinates and embedding.

Comment: I can't just integrate o(r)dr from 0 to pi/4 to find half the area, this doesn't work cause of curvature of the space. I need a reasonable meaningful definition of curvature I can use for practical intrinsic coordinate less calculations